# tagDatabase and include SQL syntax for LiquiBase?

Tags: liquibase

As suggest [official page](http://www.liquibase.org/community/index.html) I should ask this question at SO before filing bug/request.

There are XML syntax for [tagDatabase](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/tag_database.html) and [include](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/include.html).

[Official docs on SQL syntax](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html) say nothing about such abilities.

Is it possible to instruct LiquiBase to create tag or include other file in SQL sytnax?

Comment: Can you please give me a example of splitting sql file and setting different tags for different sql file in xml file?

Comment: See also this PR : [CORE-2621: Adding tagDatabase support to formatted SQL](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/843)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked current version of formatted sql parser (https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/formattedsql/FormattedSqlChangeLogParser.java) and see nothing related to tagDatabase and include. So I would expect that it is not supported. 'tagDatabase' could be implemented with an update of databasechanbgelog table, and I think that there is no such easy implementation of 'include'.

Comment: I just clone Git repo... Thanks for support! Inclusion and ordering can be archived with top level XML file. But splitting `.sql` file in order to set tag between in `master.xml` I think is bad practice. I will file enhancement to BTS.